# Python print string just above empty string in a list

Tags: python

Hello I am fairly new to python. I have a script that was given to me. I want to be able to identify the empty strings in a list. "print fileList" shows the following. Is this considered a list of lists, or strings within a list?

```
['C:/test\\07072013_0001.zip']
['C:/test\\07072013_0006.zip']
[]
['C:/test\\07072013_00018.zip']
```

There are hundreds of files. I would like it to print the name of the zip directly above the empty []. There could be multiple empties.
E.g. just print:

```
['C:/test\\07072013_0006.zip']
```

I have tried a for loop but that seems to just bypass the empty strings and only lists the zip files present in the folder. Thank you for any help.

Actual output:

> > > ================================ RESTART ================================
> > >
> > > ```
> > > ['C:/Users/cb/Desktop/data/test\\07072013_0001.zip']
> > > []
> > > ['C:/Users/cb/Desktop/data/test\\08042013_0025.zip']
> > > ['C:/Users/cb/Desktop/data/test\\08042013_0031.zip']
> > > ['C:/Users/cb/Desktop/data/test\\08042013_0037.zip']
> > > []
> > > ['C:/Users/cb/Desktop/data/test\\08042013_0049.zip']
> > > ```

```
print type(fileList)
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: Please provide your code so far.

Comment: Post the actual output of `print fileList`.

Comment: What you've shown is just 4 individual lists, but I assume there are list braces around the whole thing that you removed.

Comment: No that is the exact output, there are not braces around the whole thing. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrew No it is not, you can't get this output with `print fileList`. It looks like you're iterating over `fileList` and printing individual items.

Comment: It is calling a function called FindFiles. I am guessing the FindFiles function is manipulating it somehow. I'm not sure I can share the FindFiles function because a third party wrote most of this script.

Comment: @Andrew what does `print type(fileList)` returns?

Comment: Output doesn't make any sense (to me).

Comment: @Ashwini Hi I posted what print type returns. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew Now that's a weird output, have you tried my solution?

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I was asked to alter my method a bit. 
I want to only list the name of the zip file if there is not a corresponding zip file with the same date. This worked for what I am after.

    if len(fileList) <2:
        print fileList

Comment: -1 for not selecting a valid answer out of the 5 given and then changing what you need from the original question.

Comment: Should I start a new question then? I was asked for something different well after I started the question. I appreciate the answers but none of them worked for my original question. The output was weird as Ashwini stated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this considered a list of lists, or strings within a list?

This is a list of list.

```
[
[element], 
[element], 
[element], 
[element], 
]
```

A list of strings would be this:

```
[
'element', 
'element', 
'element', 
'element', 
]
```

> I have tried a for loop but that seems to just bypass the empty strings and only lists the zip files present in the folder.

Please post what you have tried so far, and the output it gives. I'll edit this answer with any corrections I can suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.izip` here. `itertools.izip` returns an iterator so it is memory efficient, if the list is not huge then you can also use the built-in function `zip`.

```
from itertools import izip, tee
lis = [['a'], [], ['b'], ['c'], [], [], ['d'], []]
it1, it2 = tee(lis)
next(it2)
for x, y in izip(it1, it2):
    if x and not y:
        print x
```

**output:**

```
['a']
['c']
['d']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Old variable a replaced with fileList

for indx, x in enumerate(fileList):
        if len(x) == 0:
            if (indx > 0):
                print fileList[indx-1]
```

Comment: I think you mean `enumerate`.

Comment: Yes! (and it's still cheesy, but at least it didn't drag out itertools).

Comment: Hello thanks. What from your script would I replace fileList with?

Comment: a represents the fileList.

Comment: @Jim No it is not working for me. I think the previous functions that run create a weird output like I have posted above under RESTART. According to Karan that does not look like a list or lists, or a list of strings.

Comment: if len(x) can be written if x

Comment: It's a tuple?  How was it formed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to get the previous filename:

```
fileList = [['C:/test\\07072013_0001.zip'],
            ['C:/test\\07072013_0006.zip'],
            [],
            ['C:/test\\07072013_00018.zip'],
           ]

for file, prev in zip(fileList[1:],fileList):
    if not file:
        print prev
```

This prints out:

```
['C:/test\\07072013_0006.zip']
```

Answer (score 0):

### First solution

```
ref = [
    ['a'],
    ['b'],
    [],
    [],
    ['d'],
    ['e'],
    ['f'],
    ['g'],
    [],
    ['i'],
    [],
    ['k'],
    ['l']
]

results = [ref[index - 1] for (index,item) in enumerate(ref) if (not item and index > 0 and ref[index - 1])]

print results
```

Output:

```
[['b'], ['g'], ['i']]
```

---

### Second solution

```
ref = [
    ['a'],
    ['b'],
    [],
    ['d'],
    ['e'],
    ['f'],
    ['g'],
    [],
    [],
    ['i'],
    [],
    ['k'],
    ['l']
]


def test(l):
    for (index,item) in enumerate(ref):
        if not item and index > 0 and l[index - 1]:
            yield l[index - 1][0]

for i in test(ref):
    print i

# or
print list(test(ref))
```

Output:

```
b
g
i

['b', 'g', 'i']
```

Comment: What if `ref` looks like: `[[], ['a'], ...,['l']]`?